# I don't see Do Exploratory Testing in my Test Manager 2013

Tags: automated-testing, test-management

I have Test Manager 2013 installed in my laptop. When I click on Testing Center - Test - I don't see "Do Exploratory Testing" option on it. I only see Run tests, Analyze Test runs, Verify Bugs but when I see videos on youtube they have more options. Why is that ?

Comment: Maybe missing permissions?

Answer (score 1):

As per the MSDN, your team may be using TFS version prior to 2012, in such a case you will not be able to see 'Do Exploratory testing' option in MTM 2013. You will need to use TFS version 2013 for the same.

Refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191621(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details and search for the word **'I don't see Do Exploratory Testing.'**